# Automatically trigger new request based on responose

Tags: postman, data-paging

I have API request which gives data and a link to the next page. I want postman to use this link as my next API request without my input.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors are you getting if any?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding some code in the Tests section of the postman request.
First, parse the response received after your first request using - `var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);`

Now extract the link you want to use for your next call from jsonData and then make your next request using `pm.sendRequest()`.

Refer https://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/ and https://blog.getpostman.com/2017/10/03/send-asynchronous-requests-with-postmans-pm-api/ for more info.